# c# Open Adobe LiveCycle. pdf file without typing credentials

Tags: c#, pdf, adobe

I receive pdf files that connects with Adobe LiveCycle. Everytime I need to type my login and password. Is there a way to use c# and open these files without typing credentials and saving them as not protected .pdf

Comment: I have this same question 7+ years later.  I do not need to save the PDFs as unprotected, but I really need a way to automate access and viewing them in our internal applications with our valid credentials.